# Months not showing up on x-axis using Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

As mentioned in the title. Here is current code:

```
    start_date <- as.Date(input$dateRange[1])
    end_date <- as.Date(input$dateRange[2])
    month_seq <- seq(from = start_date, to = end_date, by = "month")
    
    data$Month <- as.Date(data$Month)
    
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Month, y = AvgRating)) +
      geom_line() + 
      geom_point(aes(text = paste("Avg: ", round(AvgRating, 2), "<br>Count: ", Count))) +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
      theme_minimal() +
      labs(title = "Average Rating by Month", x = "", y = "Average Rating")
    
    plotly_graph <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text") %>%
      layout(xaxis = list(
        type = 'date',
        tickmode = "array",
        tickvals = month_seq,
        tickformat = "%b %Y",
        dtick = "M1")
      )
    
    plotly_graph
```

Not sure if this matters but it is being run in the server portion of an r Shiny app. Ch*tgpt keeps running me in circles.

Comment: Try without `shiny`. Does this behave differently on the console? If not, then I recommend removing the [tag:shiny] tag as unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I replicated your code without the plotly::layout specification and it seems to work. I have months on the x axis...
Why did you add the layout, if the default has the desired outcome?
here

```
df <- 
  tibble(
   Month = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"),
               as.Date("2019-12-01"),
               by = "month") 
  ) |> 
  mutate(AvgRating = sample(100,nrow(df)),
         Count = sample(20,nrow(df)))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = AvgRating,
                    group = 1,
                    text = 
                      paste("Avg: ", round(AvgRating, 2),
                            "\nCount: ", Count))) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b %Y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Average Rating by Month", x = "", y = "Average Rating")

library(plotly)
plotly_graph <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")

plotly_graph
```